What is the math rationale behind the inverse probability weighting?
Papers say IPTW (inverse probability weighting) is superior to PSM (propensity score matching) because it does not necessarily drop observations, whereas PSM drops those observation not paired.
IPTW is an analysis method to balance the baseline between the exposed and control groups in observational studies. IPTW creates two pseudo-cohorts and then compares the outcome of these two cohorts, making the known confounders controlled.
What is the math rationale behind the IPTW? And most importantly, how to derive the values of the outcome for those pseudo-individuals?

Inverse probability of  treatment weighting doesn't create pseudo-individuals so there's no need to derive their outcome.
The idea of IPTW is that that you have a binary treatment variable $T$, an outcome $Y$, and some confounders (all the confounders) $Z$.  You assume you can model $T$ as having been randomly assigned with probabilities $p(Z)$ that vary with $Z$. As a result, $Z$ is correlated with $T$ and a simple comparison of $Y|T=1$ and $Y|T=0$ won't estimate the effect of $T$ on $Y$. However, (by assumption) all the biases are due to differences in the distribution of $Z$, so you can reweight the data.  If you assign weights $p(Z)$ to anyone with $T=1$ and $1-p(Z)$ to anyone with $T=0$, the weighted distributions of $Z|T=1$ and $Z|T=0$ will be the same[1] and the weighted differences between $Y|T=1$ and $Y|T=0$ will estimate the effect of $T$ on $Y$.
The two pseudo-cohorts you mention are the two weighted subsets divided up by $T$. They are made of real (weighted) people, so there are no pseudo-individuals.
Another way of deriving the same estimators, which I think makes the math  clearer, is in terms of potential outcomes.  Think of each person as having two values of $Y$: their $Y$ if $Y=1$, written $Y_{T=1}$ and the corresponding $Y_{T=0}$. The thing you want to estimate is the average value of $Y_{T=1}-Y_{T=0}$, but  you only get to see one of those two outcomes for each person.
If you think of the one outcome you see as a random sample with probability $p(Z)$ from the two possible outcomes (according to which $T$ the person gets) then basic survey statistics says
$$E\left[\frac{T_i=1}{p(Z_i)}Y_{T=1}\right]=E[Y_{T=1}]$$
and
$$E\left[\frac{T_i=0}{1-p(Z_i)}Y_{T=0}\right]=E[Y_{T=0}]$$
so you can subtract those to get the effect of $T$ on $Y$.
The cost of doing the derivation via potential outcomes is that while it's mathematically simpler, it's metaphysically more expensive -- you need to think about potential outcomes. You get the same result either way, though.
And finally, this doesn't really let you keep more data than propensity-score matching in any qualitative sense:
[1] Suppose you are looking at smoking and age is one of your covariates, and no-one under 12 in your dataset smokes.  There's no way you can reweight to get the same age distribution for smokers and non-smokers if you have people under 12! The technical restriction here is that $p(Z)$ and $1-p(Z)$ must be bounded away from zero,  and that's not very different from the restriction of needing matches in propensity score analyses.

Thanks, pal. It is a little difficult for me to understand your explanation. Therefore, I searched again and found an ebook mentioned in this thread (https://rebeccabarter.com/blog/2017-07-05-ip-weighting) discussing IPTW. According to the book, the critical point is to stratify the original population as precisely as possible based on the known confounders. Then the pseudo-population can be formed and the unbiased outcome could be estimated. The book does mention the pseudo-population. Thanks.
